# How to change an Images Cross Origin attribute using loadFromJSON?

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS' loadFromJSON method to load a bunch of objects (text and images) to a canvas.

The images are coming from Google Cloud Storage. The bucket they are stored in has the correct CORS settings, for allow all for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

The images will load in OK, but when trying to save a thumbnail, using the toDataURL() method, I get:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I'm unsure why, because the images CORS settings are correct.

I know some people suggest creating a new image and setting the attribute that way, but that doesn't fit in with using the very quick and easy loadFromJSON method.

Any ideas on why the CORS settings are being ignored and anyway around this issue?

Comment: Hrm...straight JSON instructions shouldn't taint a canvas. Are you doing anything else to your canvas, like applying any image filters? Is there a background image loaded from another domain? Did you set `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` when loading the background image?

Comment: There is an overlay image, but it is loaded from the same server (it's in an assets folder, marked as a static file in App Engine) and you cannot set the cross origin attribute for that.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the form of `jsFiddle` or something similar? How does the callstack look like in the debugger?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hs9spxL4/ here you go. if you access either of the image URLs, in the header you will see it has a wildcard for CORS access. Yet when you click the button to use toDataURL, you'll see the error message.

Comment: (you may need to just single click on the canvas to make the images appear)

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying this jsfiddle.net example works, but when you run it in app engine, it stops working?

Comment: No, the jsFiddle version doesn't work. It's a demo to show you how it's broken.